# Validation rule issus

Tags: apex, validation-rule, null, required

I want to check this condition :

If the field status ( Picklist)  is "ended" , then , verify If the field description is empty , if is empty , the validation rule should work and the error message appear ( the field description is required but should not be empty / null ) , and if it is not empty don't accept any new insertion that why i used the PRIORVALUE .

My validation rule don't work correctly .

```
AND ( 
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Closed"),
PRIORVALUE(Description__c )!= Description__c ,
Description__c = null 
)
```

Comment: Your post says the status should be "ended", but your code says "Closed". Please [edit] your post to clarify.  Also, you should use the `ISBLANK()` function to compare `Description` to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your validation rule like below

AND ( ISCHANGED(Status__c ),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c, "Closed"),
ISBLANK(Description__c)
)